# Android Scoped Storage Permission for Download Folder to Download PDF

Tags: java, android, scoped-storage

I have an app that download specific pdf files using streamig Retrofit. I am upgrading my app targeting android 11. I have gone through many online documents and stackoverflow solutions and got it working. The files gets downloaded to Downloads folder.

With Scope Storage, do i need to ask for specific permission to read/write for 29 and above, as this folder is shared folder? I already have these in manifest.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="28"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I am using this to check if permission is granted

```
public static boolean isPermissionGranted(Context context){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R){
            return Environment.isExternalStorageManager();
        } else {
            int readExtStorage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            int writeExtStorage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            return readExtStorage == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && writeExtStorage == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        }
    }
```

Do I need to use this also in manifest, and if so how do i handle if permission not granted?

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I was thinking of using below, but i guess Playstore will reject my app with this absurd permission request.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package",getPackageName(),null);
            intent.setData(uri);
            permissionActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
```

Comment: anyone with suggestion ?

Comment: Got any solutions?

Comment: if the permission is not granted, trying to give yourself another, higher level permission won't likely work. The docs say, if permission isn't granted, it simply doesn't work